# Unable to install cryptography

Tags: python, lubuntu, cryptography

Lubuntu version: 20.04

I am trying to `ssh` to a cluster using `fab` but it returns an error.

I am adding a screenshot showing the traceback .

[image: error output]

I am not able to install `cryptography` through terminal by using

```
sudo apt-get install crytography
```

It returns the following message

```
unable to locate the package file
```

Comment: Please [don't post pictures of text](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4086/100397).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cryptography` is the name of the Python package in [Python Package Index (PyPI)](https://pypi.org/). This is an index of Python packages (source packages, Eggs or Wheels) only. It is independent of Linux distributions, and in source code format, even independent of operating systems and hardware architectures. So the name displayed in the Python error message is the name of the package "inside the Python ecosystem".

When Debian/Ubuntu includes Python packages into their repository as apt-installable `.dpkg` package, the package name is prefixed with `python-` or `python3-` in order to avoid name conflicts with non-Python software in the repository, to allow Python 2.x and 3.x versions of the same package to co-exist if necessary, and to identify the `.dpkg` as containing a Python package.

So, in this case, since you're using Python 2.x, to install Python package `cryptography` from an APT repository, you'll want to run `sudo apt-get install python-cryptography`.

This naming scheme is documented in [Debian Python Policy](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/python-policy/module_packages.html). And since Ubuntu takes packages from Debian, Ubuntu follows the same policy.

[A similar policy is in effect for Perl too.](https://www.debian.org/doc/packaging-manuals/perl-policy/)

Comment: I had the same issue. I fixed it using this answer, but instead of `sudo apt-get install python-cryptography`, I used `sudo apt-get install python3-cryptography`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the help.I solved the issue. As it was the issue with the version of Lubuntu.I downgraded to the 19.04 and the issue solved.